# WebPack Dev Server WebSocket Connection Stalling

Tags: javascript, proxy, websocket, webpack

Similar questions have been asked but nothing seems to specifically answer my questions. I'm trying to proxy a WebSocket connection to a Java server, but it just refuses to work; it just hangs and eventually times out. I'm using webpack-dev-server:1.16.2 with the config:

```
inline: false,
quiet: false,
proxy: {
    '/websocket': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/websocket',
        ws: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    }
}
```

There is a service running on http://localhost:8080/websocket and when I manually change the URI in the javascript it connects. I'm using the iFrame method (as suggested by the documentation) via:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/webpack-dev-server/
```

I've tried variations of the URI:

```
[http|ws]://[0.0.0.0|127.0.0.1|<host_ip>|localhost]:8080/websocket
```

I'm not using SockJS, just vanilla websocket connections. It doesn't help that it doesn't appear to log anything too which suggests it's not hitting the proxy.

I'm stumped, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it may be related to [chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#112](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/112). I've noticed if I warm the proxy up by doing a basic GET request first the it gets a little further and I get '[HPM] Upgrading to WebSocket', but it still ultimately fails.